# Django admin showing incorrect value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a display error/bug that I don't quite get. In my Django admin interface a field that has a value of either `None`, `1`, `2` or `3`, the Admin interface always shows `None` while the value is clearly existent in the database and it also shows up when I want to edit an object.

This is my object with said field.

```
class EventPerson(models.Model):
    status_choices = (
        ('1', 'Ausstehend'),
        ('2', 'Angenommen'),
        ('3', 'Abgelehnt'),
    )
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=status_choices)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    points = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.event.event_name

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['person', 'event']
```

And i display everything except for the primary ID in the admin interface with:

```
for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(miggser.models):
    if inspect.isclass(obj):
        if isinstance(obj, ModelBase):
            if not obj._meta.abstract:
                try:
                    class DisplayAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
                        list_display = [field.name for field in obj._meta.fields if not field.primary_key]
                    admin.site.register(obj, DisplayAdmin)
                except AlreadyRegistered:
                    pass
```

I also made some screenshots since my english skills aren't too great when it comes to  graphical or display stuff...

Table view `None` is shown here:
[image: Here is the error]

and this is what shows when I want to edit an object:

[image: This works fine]

I don't really know what causes this to show `None` and not a number or string linked to the number. Every other model also shows all it's field regardless of datatype.

I also have another object that works similar (Male = 1, Female = 2) and this shows up correctly.

The only thing i could relate to is because the model is a M2M that is used with `models.ManyToManyField(Person, through="EventPerson")`

If I'm missing somethign out please tell me and I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: how is the `list_display` in the model admin defined for this model ?

Comment: @karthikr just took that variable from the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial02/#customize-the-admin-change-list). I don't know how it works exactly (i'm still pretty new to programming and django) since I didn't dig too deep into django itself.

Comment: Oh I actually just found the variable: it's in a file called options.py (by django itself) and is defined by `list_display = ('__str__',)`